# Excel multi-variable condition. IF function

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

```
Factors:
System 1 Production(S1)= 100
System 2 Production(S2)= 99
Job Requires (J) = 100
```

Having difficulty building a spreadsheet which populates either the work "Reconciled" or "Out of tolerance". All three factors must reconcile or the job is out of tolerance.

My attempt below.

```
=IF(S1>=J, IF(S2 = J, " ", "Overproduced"), IF(S2=S1, "Under Produced`enter 
code here`", " "))
```

Comment: What is "J" in this context?

Comment: Just a variable to represent amount of finished goods a particular job asks for. We use two different systems and we have to reconcile our production of each job. So i.e. Job - "J" requires us to produce 100 boxes, system 1 says we produced 100 and system 2 says we produced 99. This would yield as 'Under Production'

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the IF statement, Excel won't know what "J" is, and give you a "#NAME?" error.

Suggest putting J's value into a cell, and naming the cell, e.g. "JobRequires".
Then reference that name in your formula:

```
=IF(S1>=JobRequires, IF(S2 =JobRequires, " ", "Overproduced"), IF(S2=S1, "Under Produced", " "))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do have figures within each cell. I was just simplifying it. Or so I thought haha. I tend to do that.

Comment: No problem. Mark as the answer if you're happy with it.